# After Facebook signs a user in, what login name to store in the app's DB?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

After Facebook signs in for a user, what is a proper Login name and email to use to store this user into the app's Database?

Is there any docs on it?  I haven't seen any yet.  Is it the same for new JS SDK and old JS SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every user would have a unique facebook user id number that is probably what your looking for

Comment: we can use `__facebook_user_67867867` as the login name, but is it already good enough?  Can't another person fake this in the cookie, or is the proper way to call a function or somehow check other cookies to verify that indeed this is the person logged in by Facebook?  Otherwise, if we show the "user's preferred product list" which is on our DB, we don't go to Facebook to fetch any data, but just show our DB data, how do we know the user is really that user signed in by Facebook?